# Using RegExp to find what's inside part of an HTML attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I had some HTML that looks like the following:

```
<input type="text" data-text="mytext{someothertext}">
```

How would I use a Regular Expression to 'pull out' what's inside the curly braces inside the 'data-text' attribute. I know this is probably looking rather bizarre and also weird, but I am trying something out in a new project. And the curly braces here are not to represent JSON or anything like it.

What I want to be able to do is console.log() what's inside of the curlies!

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do this :

```
var myText= myElement.dataset['text'].match(/{([^}]+)}/)[1]
```

This sets `myText` to `"someothertext"`.

If you can't use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset) (for example because you want to be compatible with old browsers), then you have to use getAttribute :

```
var myText= myElement.getAttribute('data-text').match(/{([^}]+)}/)[1]
```

Comment: Thanks Dystroy! Out of curiosity what does the [1] do at the end? Haven't seen that before.

Comment: `match` returns an array with the global match (`"{someothertext}"`) at index 0 and the inner match at index 1.

Comment: I see. Would it be possible to use .test() too?

Comment: You don't need to use `test`. If you want to check that the string is correct, first use `match` and then check that the size of the array is 2.

Comment: Ahh okay :) for some reason it's giving me: Cannot call method 'match' of null. I've logged the element itself in Console and it exists, just the match isn't working.

Comment: It looks like the attribute value isn't found.

Comment: The attribute value will change, what I wanted to achieve was logging whatever is between those {curlies}! :) is that do-able?

Comment: My mistake copying things back incorrectly, I'd changed my HTML data-*. Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate it.